# Three js hiding multiple objects just hide single object

Tags: javascript, debugging, three.js, rendering

I was running into a problem when I was setting my light objects name `light.name = 'globalLight'` and im making variable that is `lightGlobal = scene.getObjectByName('globalLight');` but when i tried to hide using `lightGlobal.visible = false;` it was just let the other light wasn’t hide the green one Is `light0` and the blue one is `light1` render example [The rendered image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTjuQ.png)
The problem [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oldn.png)

As you can see the blue light is gone but the green one won’t hide

My code :

```
ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
scene.add( ambient );
lightCam = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.0 );
light0 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x0000ff, 1.0 );
light0.position.set( 4.0, 4.0, 4.0 );
light0.castShadow = true;
light0.name = "globalLight";
light1 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x00ff00, 1.0 );
light1.position.set( 4.0, 4.0, -4.0 );
light1.castShadow = true;
light1.name = "globalLight";

scene.add( light0, light1 );

globalLight = scene.getObjectByName( "globalLight", true );
globalLight.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object3D.name` has to be unique. Hence, naming two lights in the same way is not supported. `Object3D.getObjectByName()` will return the first object that matches the given name.

One solution for this problem is to use `Object3D.userData` and define a custom property like:

```js
light0.userData.tag = 'globalLight';
```

You can then consider to enhance `Object3D` by the following method:

```js
THREE.Object3D.prototype.getObjectsByTag = function( tag, result ) {

  // check the current object

  if ( this.userData.tag === tag ) result.push( this );
  
  // check children

  for ( let i = 0, l = this.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    const child = this.children[ i ];

    child.getObjectsByTag( tag, result );

  }
   
  return result;

};
```